# Stop selenium webdriver from running ancestor tests

Tags: c#, inheritance, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to a run a number of tests.

I have a base class which includes a lot of tests.

In my second class, called 'People', I have another set of tests. The People class inherits the Base class.

I initialise some of the tests in the base class, when run when I run the tests for the People class. My problem is, it also runs all the tests in the base class, whether or not I initialise them. This leaves me running 100 tests, which takes forever, and when I only really wanted to test about 50.

Is there any setting to stop selenium web driver from doing this?

Comment: Nothing to do with Selenium, but rather the testing framework you are using. Are you using MSTest, NUnit, MbUnit etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, it is normal. Your test framework will load your class 'People' and search for all tests. Since the tests defined in your base class belongs also to your class 'People' (for the framework it makes no difference), the framework will execute them as well.

You should'nt put any test in your base class nor initialise thing for your class 'People'. The base class should contains only utility/convenience methods and the startup/shutdown methods that are common to ALL your tests (for People and the rest).

In sub class 'People', you put all the tests and the startup/shutdown methods related to 'People'.
In sub class 'Toto', you put all the tests and the startup/shutdown methods related to 'Toto'.
etc.

Hope this help.